# How to get contents from a custom address field

Tags: netsuite

I have a few custom fields on the customer address form. The issue is I can't find a way to place the values of the fields on the sales order. I would like certain fields to be updated on the SO if the address is changed.

There doesn't seem to be a list/record that would expose the list of addresses (or just those fields) so I could set them as defaults or reference in a formula or a workflow. I can only expose them through saved search. Is that the way to go? Or is scripting the only way to update SO fields from bespoke address fields?